# HtmlPurifier - keeps removing my tables - what is the right config?

Tags: config, htmlpurifier

I have a table that keeps beeing removed by html purifier
the content is an email that needs to be populated

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>fieldA</th>
    <th>fieldB</th>
    <th>fieldC</th>
    <th>fieldD</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<!--[[[order_list]]]-->     
</tbody>
</table>
```

where < ! - - [[[order_list]]] - - > is replaced at runtime, but htmlpurifier keeps removing my table (the comments are there for ckeditor, otherwise it gets removed)

I tried to disable the AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty :

```
 $config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
 $config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty', false);
 Validator::$purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
 $val=Validator::$purifier->purify($data);
```

it does not work at all, the table yet gets removed

how can I fix this ?

thanks

[edit: tried this so far...]

```
$config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
//                        $config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty', false);
// ----------------------------------------------- from stackoverflow
$def = $config->getHtmlDefinition(true);

$element = $def->addElement(
                            'tbody',
                            false,
                            'Flow', // <-- here is the change - we're not requiring 'tr' any more
                            'Common',
                            [
                                'align' => 'Enum#left,center,right,justify,char',
                                'charoff' => 'Length',
                                'valign' => 'Enum#top,middle,bottom,baseline',
                            ]
                        );

$config->set('HTML.AllowedComments', array('[[[[order_list]]]'));

Validator::$purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're encountering is that `tbody` [cannot be empty by the HTML standard (*"Each row group must contain at least one row"*)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) (and much of HTML Purifier's security comes from strategically requiring the HTML to be standards-compliant), a comment does not count as content, and it's thus removed. That said, the ["living" standard of HTML doesn't require this (*"Zero or more tr ..."*)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tbody-element), so it should be safe to fiddle with.

In any case, you can see HTML Purifier's requirement in the file `library/HTMLPurifier/HTMLModule/Tables.php`:

```
$this->addElement('tbody', false, 'Required: tr', 'Common', $cell_align);
```

If you want to overwrite the way HTML Purifier treats `tbody` elements, check out the [Customize](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) documentation. Your solution would look a little like this (although this example does not cache the HTML definition, you may want to fiddle with yours until yours does):

```
require_once (__DIR__ . '/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');

$dirty_html = '<table>
<thead>
    <th>fieldA</th>
    <th>fieldB</th>
    <th>fieldC</th>
    <th>fieldD</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!--[[[order_list]]]-->
</tbody>
</table>';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

$def = $config->getHtmlDefinition(true);

$element = $def->addElement(
    'tbody',
    false,
    'Flow', // <-- here is the change - we're not requiring 'tr' any more
    'Common',
    [
        'align' => 'Enum#left,center,right,justify,char',
        'charoff' => 'Length',
        'valign' => 'Enum#top,middle,bottom,baseline',
    ]
);

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

This spits out (though I removed the whitespace):

```
<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>
```

If the result still does not seem right to you because `thead` was emptied out, know that `thead` was emptied because you have "stray" `th` tags in it - they're not wrapped by `tr`. That [is required to be standards-compliant even by the "living" standard (as it only permits `tr` children)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-thead-element), but you could of course also change *that* behaviour by tweaking HTML Purifier if you want. That might have unintended consequences for browser rendering, though, be careful!

That said, this alone will still kill the `<!-- [[[order_list]]] -->` comment, since HTML Purifier by default disallows all comments for security reasons (there've historically been quite a few browser exploits busting out of HTML comments, although not so much in recent years).

To fix this, you can whitelist the specific comment you want to preserve like this:

```
...
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.AllowedComments', ['[[[order_list]]]']);

$def = $config->getHtmlDefinition(true);
...
```

This will spit out (though I again removed the whitespace):

```
<table><thead></thead><tbody><!--[[[order_list]]]--></tbody></table>
```

Comment: it kind of work, te table stays, but the precious comment gets removed..I updated my question with the code

Comment: @user7082181 For the problem with the comment, see http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.AllowedComments - try adding `$config->set('HTML.AllowedComments', ['[[[order_list]]]']);` after the instantiation of `$config`

Comment: I updated my question ,it is not working, now the comment is totaly discarded

Comment: Cannot set directive after finalization invoked on line 726 in file ..validator.php

Comment: You really need to put it immediately after the instantiation of `$config` as I mentioned; if you put it later, your config has already been "finalised" because it's been used in the HTML definition. So look for `$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();` in your code and put `$config->set('HTML.AllowedComments', ['[[[order_list]]]']);` immediately after it.

Comment: I find it strange that array('[[[[order_list]]]') does not work while ['[[[order_list]]]'] does

Comment: The first variant should still work, as long as your string is `'[[[order_list]]]'` and not `'[[[[order_list]]]'` (note the different number of brackets).